# React (Native) Higher Order Component with animation logic and progress pass-through

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, higher-order-components

Currently, I have multiple Views that can be dismissed by a drag-down gesture. When dragging down, the view gets smaller until it reaches a point where I call `goBack()` on the navigator, dismissing it completely.

Now since I don't want to implement this logic in many files over and over again, I've tried creating an HoC to write the dismiss animation logic once and keep my other components focused on their specific tasks. I also wanted to pass a `dismissAnimationProgress` value through to my wrapped components, so they can handle some extra logic while the user drags down (such as fading some things out).

This is my `DismissableView.tsx`:

```js
export interface DismissableViewProps {
    dismissProgress: Reanimated.Value<number>;
}

export default function DismissableView<TView extends React.Component<TViewProps>, TViewProps extends DismissableViewProps>(
    WrappedComponent: TView,
    props: TViewProps,
): React.ReactElement {
    const { navigation, ...passThroughProps } = props;

    const navigateBack = useMemo(() => navigation.pop(), [navigation]);
    const gestureHandler = usePanGestureHandler();
    const dismissAnimationProgress = useValue(0); // Animation from 0 -> 1, where 1 is dismiss.
    const cardBorderRadius = useMemo(() => {
        return Reanimated.interpolate(dismissAnimationProgress, {
            inputRange: [0, 1],
            outputRange: [0, 30],
            extrapolate: Extrapolate.CLAMP,
        });
    }, [dismissAnimationProgress]);
    const viewScale = useMemo(() => {
        return Reanimated.interpolate(dismissAnimationProgress, {
            inputRange: [0, 1],
            outputRange: [1, 0.8],
            extrapolate: Extrapolate.CLAMP,
        });
    }, [dismissAnimationProgress]);
    useCode(
        () => [
            cond(eq(gestureHandler.state, State.ACTIVE), [
                set(
                    dismissAnimationProgress,
                    Reanimated.interpolate(gestureHandler.translation.y, {
                        inputRange: [0, SCREEN_HEIGHT * 0.2],
                        outputRange: [0, 1],
                    }),
                ),
            ]),
            cond(eq(gestureHandler.state, State.END), [
                set(dismissAnimationProgress, timing({ from: dismissAnimationProgress, to: 0, duration: 200, easing: Easing.out(Easing.ease) })),
            ]),
            cond(greaterOrEq(dismissAnimationProgress, 1), [call([], navigateBack)]),
        ],
        [],
    );
    const viewStyle = useMemo(() => {
        return { transform: [{ scale: viewScale, borderRadius: cardBorderRadius }] };
    }, [viewScale, cardBorderRadius]);

    return (
        <PanGestureHandler {...gestureHandler.gestureHandler}>
            <Reanimated.View style={viewStyle}>
                <WrappedComponent {...passThroughProps} navigation={navigation} dismissAnimationProgress={dismissAnimationProgress} />
            </Reanimated.View>
        </PanGestureHandler>
    );
}
```

Which does not work as expected, since the component's properties won't get passed through (because they won't get supplied in the parameter), and the dismissAnimationProgress prop also won't get set.

In my Navigator (`@react-navigation/stack`) I'm using it like this:

```js
import ProfileScreen from '../screens/social/ProfileScreen';
import DismissableView from '../components/DismissableView';

                                 // No parameter for props here
const DismissableProfileScreen = DismissableView(ProfileScreen);

                                  // Props include { route, navigation } for "ProfileScreen"
const Stack = createStackNavigator<MainStackNavigatorProps>();
export default function MainStackNavigator(): JSX.Element {
  return ( 
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="ProfileScreen" component={DismissableProfileScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator> );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you want to declare HOC, you actually need to declare `DismissableView` as Father component of both "himself" and of the component it will receive -

```
const dismissableView = <TView extends object>(Component: React.ComponentType<P>) =>
  const DismissableView: React.FC<TView & DismissableViewProps> = props => {
```

Another approach is to treat `DismissableView` as

```
const withDismissableScreen = Component => <DismissableView> <Component/> </DismissableView>;


<Stack.Screen name="ProfileScreen" component={withDismissableScreen(ProfileScreen)} />
```

And now the declaration of `DismissableScreen` will still be in one line, but you get the component through `props.children`

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't get your first example working, could you give me a full code example on this? Thanks!

Comment: please update your question to contain your current code and issues, otherwise it impossible to try helping you in terms of specific code...